# How to add new entities to frontend and backend?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

We have separated frontend and backend and used the `jhipster --skip-server` command to create frontend and used `jhipster --skip-client` to create backend service.

Now we would like to add more entities to frontend and backend.

So, how to generate separate frontend and backend code for an entity?

Gateway is the only backend service we have now. Postgres is our relational database.

jHipster registry is also installed to monitor services.

Comment: Why using skip-client and skip-server if you are using a gateway? The gateway without any option is a way to separate frontend code from backend services.

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou for reply. We already have jHipster installed and created gateway with UI. Now, we would like to create another microservice called Employee Management. This Employee management will have UI to add, update and delete employees and backend to perform the DB transactions. I would like to use JDL to create entities. So all required code will be generated. Question he is. Where should I execute JDL command to create entities and other required java and react code? Should I execute it on Gateway (which has UI) or the newly created Employee Management microservice?

Comment: It depends on how you structured your JDL, if you created a single multi apps JDL and respected sub folder names, it should be run only once from parent directory like in https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications#complete-example-breakdowns 
If you created a JDL per service for your entities, then you have to run in both gateway and services: first in service, then in gateway.